# Create Generic Function For Database Selects

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm developing an iPhone app. I've got a function that reads data from a sqlite database and puts the results into an array. Everything works fine. Here is part of the function that fills the array:

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    NSString *aVar1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
    NSString *aVar2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

    NSArray  *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aVar1,aVar2,nil];
    [returnArray addObject:anArray]
    [anArray release];
}
//return the array
```

I want to make this function more generic so that it takes a sql statement string as a parameter, and returns a mutablearray of arrays, no matter how many columns are in the result set.

Is there a way to do this?  The solution doesn't have to include arrays -- could be any collection object. I'm just looking for a way to make the function re-usable for other queries to the same database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something like:

```
int numCols = sqlite3_column_count(compiledStatement);
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        [array addObject:
         [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
          (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, i)]];
    }
    [result addObject:array];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSArray *)executeQueryAndReturnArray:(NSString *)query {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"[SQLITE] Error when preparing query!");
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSMutableArray *row = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (int i = 0; i < sqlite3_column_count(statement); i++) {
                int colType = sqlite3_column_type(statement, i);
                id value;
                if (colType == SQLITE_TEXT) {`enter code here`
                    const unsigned char *col = sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                    value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", col];
                } else if (colType == SQLITE_INTEGER) {
                    int col = sqlite3_column_int(statement, i);
                    value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:col];
                } else if (colType == SQLITE_FLOAT) {
                    double col = sqlite3_column_double(statement, i);
                    value = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:col];
                } else if (colType == SQLITE_NULL) {
                    value = [NSNull null];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"[SQLITE] UNKNOWN DATATYPE");
                }
                [row addObject:value];
            }
            [result addObject:row];
        }
        return result;
    }
    return nil;
}
```